# Can't make cloth collide with object when cloth mesh is vertices & edges (no faces) [video example included]

Tags: cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation

See this video for example: [Watch video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/2uZb0uyvKow).

When I try to create a scene with a mesh that has no faces (removed faces from a plane so that it is a line: edges with 5 vertices). It has a cloth modifier. Below it is a plane - subdivided a few times - with a cloth collision modifier. When I run the animation playback and move the cloth object, it passes through the collision object without being affected by it.

Is there a way I can make the cloth line be affected by the collision plane?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cloth (or any other simulation) calculation needs faces to be able to calculate the physics, without any faces there is no geometry to generate collisions. I am not sure, but I don't think it will work with a wire only mesh.

Comment: why are you trying to use a mesh without faces? Maybe there is an alternative solution to what you want, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 2):

While you can't do collisions with edge only mesh objects, to get around this I just add "tags" to my vertices. They are small triangular faces that allow for the collisions to be calculated.

Then I either enable collisions on my base mesh or add dummy faces with collisions parented to the base mesh.

[image: tags]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Cloth simulations need faces to work due to the Spring and Stiffness algorithms that it needs to work out between verts in opposing corners of faces.